# I have several user stories which will be provided by a new application, where do I detail setting up the new application itself?

Tags: agile, scrum, task-organization, azure-devops

We have a feature like "new command-line query tool" and stories like:

- As a user, I can do X
- As a user, I can do Y
- As a user, I can do Z

Where/how do I detail "create the test harness application"? The stories focus us on what is needed but whichever one we do first, the developer will have some setup overhead.

Would we typically:

1. wait until we start the first Story and add tasks for creating the application during the sprint planning meeting?
2. create a dedicated story "I can launch the application from the command line?"
3. Create a task directly on the feature (we've using DevOps and the tool does influence workflow to an extent).
4. something else

Comment: Another good one (and possibly a better duplicate): [What to put in the sprint backlog in the first weeks of development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/433122/118878)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a setup period, sometimes called "sprint zero" or a "design sprint" where you would have a bunch of standard tasks,

- setup the source control
- create a project in JIRA
- hire developers
- whatever doesn't fit into "normal work"

I guess the idea is that these kinds of thing you need to do, but aren't "programming" so you don't want to change your normal iterative "lets write code" methodology to accommodate them. You still have to do them, so you have this extra not really following the full process, bit at the start of a project where you are just running through a checklist for getting stuff ready to program.

In your case it sounds like you need a few things such as

- Set up source control
- create template projects/solution/directory structure
- create CI pipeline

Hopefully you write new programs frequently enough that these things are wrote tasks, you copy from a template or the last project you did. So you don't need to estimation and breaking down etc. It tends to be done fairly quickly by a single person and then you can get on with the "real work"